# DNS Domain Forward

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

How do I setup a domain to forward to another domain via DNS or apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DNS does not know what a redirect is, all it knows is how to assign a domain to a given ip by either using a Canonical name or an IP.

So the first step is to create an A name for the domain you want to redirect in your DNS to the apache server IP:

Let's say your apache server ip is 10.0.0.1 so in the DNS record of the domain you want to redirect you would need to have the follow entries:

```
domain.com.    IN    A        10.0.0.1
www            IN    CNAME    domain.com.
```

Restart/reload your dns server to make the changes apply.

---

If the domain you want to redirect is being hosted on the same server, it makes things a lot simple on the apache server, all you need to do is to add the domains on the ServerAlias example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mymaindomain.com
    ServerAlias myredirecteddomain.com myotherredirecteddomain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/domain/public_html 
</virtualhost>
```

If the destination domain is not being hosted on the same server then you can do the follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myredirecteddomain.com
    ServerAlias www.myredirecteddomain.com myotherredirecteddomain.com www.myotherredirecteddomain.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.redirecteverythinghere.com/
</virtualhost>
```

---

Another option is to use the .htaccess if that given domain is already being redirected to your main domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^long-name.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.short-name.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the site will serve requests for the domain you want to forward, just create a DNS CNAME record from the forwarded domain to the target domain name.

If the site is a name based virtual host, you may need to also add the forwarded domain name to the VirtualHost section as a ServerAlias.

Comment: How can I use a cname entry to forward the domain completely?  I only want to forward short-domain.com to long-domain.com, ignoring any /index.html or anything past it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forward the domain, set the DNS A record to forward to the server.  You should have an MX record for the domain.  It should point to a server which will handle your mail, especially for hostmaster@short-domain.com.

In apache follow the options [Prix](https://serverfault.com/users/45278/prix) gave using short-domain, to do the redirect.  The following rewrite ruleset will forward requests from short-domain to long-domain.  long-domain.com does not need to be hosted on the same server as short-domain.  Use the appropriate domains.  If you omit the RewriteCond statement all matching requests will be redirected.

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   short-domain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://long-domain.com$1 [L,R=301]

These rules would normally be placed in a VirtualHost definition.